# How split data with [/ -]

Tags: jquery, html, date-formatting

I need to split a string that represents date. This date is represent in this way `dd/mm/yyyy` or `dd-mm-yyyy`.

My code is (the current string is format in `mm/dd/yyyy`):

```
<input type="data" id="dat">
.....
var dataString=$('#dat').val();
    dataString=dataString.split('/ -');
    //now I can try to print years so
    console.log(dataString[2]);
```

The program prints me "undefined". Anyone can help pe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, It will work for both format. First I replaced '-' with '/' so that we get the date in same format(dd/mm/yyyy) then split.

```
 $(function(){
    var dataString=$('#dat').val();
    dataString=dataString.replace('-','/').split('/');
    alert(dataString[2])
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the first index of your array dataString is 0

So the code should be :

```
dataString=dataString.split('/ -');
//now I can try to print years so
console.log(dataString[1]);
```

Note the index of the array is 1 and not 2 ;)

Comment: Note that you should not split on '/ -' (I suppose you want to split date like 01/02/2016 or 01-02-2016? Then you should split on '-' or '/' depending on your date format...

Answer (score 0):

I think your split method should look like this :

```
dataString=dataString.split('/');  

  <input type="data" id="dat">
.....
var dataString=$('#dat').val();
    dataString=dataString.split('/ **-**'); - without this
    //now I can try to print years so
    console.log(dataString[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to correctly split `dd/mm/yyyy` or `dd-mm-yyyy` is to use this RegExp into split:

`.split(/\/|-/g)`

- `/` mean, opening regex expression
- `\/` mean split by `/` char (an escape `\` is used to not close expression).
- `|` mean or
- `-` mean split by `-` char.
- `/` mean, end of regex expression
- `g` is an option to split all this char and not only the first.

so in your example:

```
var dataString = $('#dat').val(); // `dd/mm/yyyy` or `dd-mm-yyyy`
    dataString = dataString.split(/\/|-/g); // [dd, mm, yyyy]
console.log(dataString[2]);
```

Exemple of regex on several dates:

```js
alert("12-12-2012".split(/\/|-/g)); // [12, 12, 2012]
alert("12/12/2012".split(/\/|-/g)); // [12, 12, 2012]
alert("12-12/2012".split(/\/|-/g)); // [12, 12, 2012]
```